# How to find the eigenvalues of the following matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

So I have to find the eigenvalues of this matrix: $\begin{bmatrix}-7/9&-4/9&8/9\\-4/9&-1/9&2/9\\2/9&-4/9&8/9\end{bmatrix}$.

What I did is start by writing it like this: $\begin{bmatrix}-7/9 - \lambda&-4/9&8/9\\-4/9&-1/9-\lambda&2/9\\2/9&-4/9&8/9-\lambda\end{bmatrix}$ and then row reducing it to this: $\begin{bmatrix}-7/9 - \lambda&-4/9&8/9\\-4/9&-1/9-\lambda&2/9\\0&-1+\lambda&1-\lambda\end{bmatrix}$. Then I found the determinate of this by expanding the bottom row. So I did this: $(-7/9 - \lambda)(2/9) + 32/81$ = $(-1)(2/9 - 2/9\lambda)(-1+\lambda)$ = $(2/9\lambda - 2/9)(-1+\lambda)$

Then for the 3rd column: $(-7/9 - \lambda)(-1/9 - \lambda)$ = $\lambda^2 + 8/9\lambda + 7/81 - 16/81$ = $(\lambda^2 + 8/9\lambda -1/9)(1-\lambda)$

So then I combine the two equations: $-(1+\lambda)((2/9\lambda - 2/9) + (\lambda^2 + 8/9\lambda-1/9))$ = $-(1+\lambda)(\lambda^2+10/9\lambda-1/3)$ and then I factor the polynomial to find out what lambda is.

The problem is I don't think my answer is correct since I can't factor my degree 2 polynomial where lambda equals two whole numbers. So where did I mess up in my answer?

Sidenote: I did try this as well by factoring out 1/9 first and I STILL GOT THE WRONG ANSWER. So can someone please help me and tell why I keep getting the wrong answer because this is very confusing and I really need some help.

Comment: I've never done this with fractions before so I didn't know if that would change the eigenvalues or not.

Comment: The eigenvalues will be the numbers $\lambda$ such that $Av=\lambda v$.  How do the numbers $\lambda'$ differ from $\lambda$ if instead we consider $(9A)v=\lambda' v$?

Comment: For any $c\ne 0$ we have $Ax=\lambda x$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $(cA)x=(c\lambda)x$.

Comment: Ok I'll try doing that but do I have to factor out a 1/9 in order to get the right answer? I just want to make sure I didn't make a mistake in my answer and that not factoring out 1/9 is why I didn't get the correct answer.

Comment: @davidmah You don't, but your answer is incorrect. The easy way to tell is that this is a singular matrix (column $3$ is $-2$ times column $2$) and thus shouldn't have a constant term.

Comment: Ok I did it with factoring 1/9 out and I'm still getting the wrong answer. So back to my original question, at which step did I make my mistake?

Comment: I double checked and triple checked every single equation that I did and they all look good but yet I'm not getting right answer. Can someone please help me with this? I really have 100% no idea why I keep getting the wrong answer.

Comment: Can you post all your steps that you did because I'm still EXTREMELY confused as to why I keep getting the wrong answer. Based on the way I've been taught to do this, I should be getting the right answer but I'm not and I have no idea why.

Comment: So I'm finding the determinate. That is what I am doing to solve this equation. So with finding the determinate of the matrix while subtracting lambda from the diagonals, then am I supposed to do something completely different than how I was taught to do it. If I'm supposed to do this in a COMPLETELY different way then HOW AM I SUPPOSED TO DO THIS! Again, I knew I had to find the determinate and I know that my equations are correct but there's clearly something wrong here and I want to know what it is. How do you keep getting $λ−λ^3$ when I struggle like crazy to get that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** I recommend you factor out a $\dfrac{1}{9}$ to reduce the possibility of errors, so repeat this approach.

We want to find the determinant of

$$\begin{vmatrix}-7/9 - \lambda&-4/9&8/9\\-4/9&-1/9-\lambda&2/9\\2/9&-4/9&8/9-\lambda\end{vmatrix}=0$$

Expanding along the top row since there are no zeros to take advantage of, we have:

$$\left(-\dfrac{7}{9}-\lambda \right)\begin{vmatrix}-\dfrac{1}{9}-\lambda &\dfrac{2}{9}\\-\dfrac{4}{9}&\dfrac{8}{9}-\lambda\end{vmatrix} + \dfrac{4}{9} \begin{vmatrix}-\dfrac{4}{9}&\dfrac{2}{9}\\\dfrac{2}{9}&\dfrac{8}{9}-\lambda\end{vmatrix} + \dfrac{8}{9} \begin{vmatrix}-\dfrac{4}{9} &-\dfrac{1}{9}-\lambda\\\dfrac{2}{9}&-\dfrac{4}{9}\end{vmatrix}$$

Hopefully, you can take it from here and arrive at:

$$\lambda - \lambda^3 = 0 \implies \lambda_{1,2,3} = -1, 0, 1$$

**Update** Expanding the three determinants, we have

$$\left(\lambda-\frac{7}{9}\right) \left(\lambda^2-\frac{7 \lambda}{9}\right)+\frac{4}{9} \left(\frac{4 \lambda}{9}-\frac{4}{9}\right)+\frac{8}{9} \left(\frac{2 \lambda}{9}+\frac{2}{9}\right)$$

This reduces to

$$\dfrac{49 \lambda}{81}-\lambda^3 + \dfrac{16 (\lambda-1)}{81} + \dfrac{16 (\lambda+1)}{81} = \dfrac{49 \lambda}{81}-\lambda^3 + \dfrac{32 \lambda}{81} = \lambda - \lambda^3$$

Comment: Ok so what I did was I did a row reduction which left a zero at the bottom of the first column and then I expanded along the bottom row. Did my row operations change the determinate which is why I kept arriving at the wrong answer?

Comment: Well that was a method that I was told could make things easier. So what row operations wouldn't change the determinate? What if column 1 in both row 3 and row 2 were the same thing and all I had to do was say R3 - R2. Could I always do that and never change the determinate?

Comment: So I did what you did but I keep ending up with $49/81 \lambda - \lambda^3$. Do you know why I keep getting this?

Comment: See update - this is why we could have gotten rid of the $\dfrac{1}{9}$ and done some very careful reductions, although I think the first change makes it palatable.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the matrix with row operations can indeed make finding its determinant easier, but you have to do it correctly. It looks like you tried to add $1/2$ times the second row to the third, but you got the wrong answer. The second element should be $-(1+\lambda)/2$.

You do have to be careful when doing this because some row operations change the determinant by a constant factor. For the purpose of finding eigenvalues, however, you can ignore this since all of those constant multipliers will factor out at the end.